# Java android OutOfMemoryError in SensorEventListener

Tags: java, android

I have a OutOfMemoryError in class in which I implements a SensorEventListener.  In logs here sometimes I have a OutOfMemoryError

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        gravity = event.values;
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        geomagnetic = event.values;
    }
    if (gravity != null && geomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity, geomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            float azimuthInRadians = orientation[0];
            float azimuthInDegress = (float)Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadians);
            if (azimuthInDegress < 0.0f) {
                azimuthInDegress += 360.0f;
            }
            azimuth = (int) azimuthInDegress;
            Hawk.put(HawkConst.AZIMUTH, azimuth);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a logs which I have. Sometimes I have this error but no always

```
  at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.<init>(FastXmlSerializer.java:55)
   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:177)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:596)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:511)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:532)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:454)
   at com.orhanobut.hawk.SharedPreferencesStorage.put(SharedPreferencesStorage.java:23)
   at com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk.put(Hawk.java:63)
   at pl.***.****.worker.Tracker.onSensorChanged(Tracker.java:154)
   at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:474)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception including its stacktrace?

Comment: Which line in the code you posted is line 154?

Comment: @Loyalar                  Hawk.put(HawkConst.AZIMUTH, azimuth);

Comment: I'd say that you simply put too much data into shared prefs, which cause OOM

Comment: So I have to move this data too SQLite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are doing some heavy lifting in your onSensorChanged() callback. So in your callback you are calling SharedPreferences. Reason why it is bad is that onSensorChanged() is called everytime there is new value from sensor, based on you listener config this might happen multiple time a second. This means that you are trying to save to file (with sharedpreferences) multiple times a sec. This requires a lot of allocations on andorid side of things and might result in OutOfMemoryError.

To solve this I would advise storing value in variable and only execute save in some constant intervals or based on some events (button click, lifecycle event, etc.).

Also I see that you are using .commit() which blocks thread till file is saved, you could try to play around with .apply(), which moves commiting action to other thread. Reagardless you need to limit how many times you are using Sharedpreferences.